# Port program that uses CreateEvent and WaitForMultipleObjects to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, winapi, events

I need to port a multiprocess application that uses the Windows API functions `SetEvent`, `CreateEvent` and `WaitForMultipleObjects` to Linux. I have found many threads concerning this issue, but none of them provided a reasonable solution for my problem.

I have an application that forks into three processes and manages thread workerpool of one process via these Events.

I had multiple solutions to this issue. One was to create FIFO special files on Linux using `mkfifo` on linux and use a select statement to awaken the threads. The Problem is that this solution will operate differently than `WaitForMultipleObjects`. For Example if 10 threads of the workerpool will wait for the event and I call `SetEvent` five times, exactly five workerthreads will wake up and do the work, when using the FIFO variant in Linux, it would wake every thread, that i in the select statement and waiting for data to be put in the fifo. The best way to describe this is that the Windows API kind of works like a global Semaphore with a count of one.

I also thought about using `pthreads` and `condition variables` to recreate this and share the variables via shared memory (`shm_open` and `mmap`), but I run into the same issue here!

What would be a reasonable way to recreate this behaviour on Linux? I found some solutions doing this inside of a single process, but what about doing this with between multiple processes?

Any ideas are appreciated (Note: I do not expect a full implementation, I just need some more ideas to get myself started with this problem).

Comment: I had a quick look at the WINE source and it seems that [the function](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/cbaab82d086e36dacaa22c6adf80f9114bb820fb/dlls/kernel32/sync.c#L143) is ultimately implemented with the help of a [runtime service](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/e395d4e766ef60030ee05947ffc9fac0c3fbe84b/dlls/ntdll/sync.c#L969) that uses [sockets to do the IPC](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/54633e3956e6b3c4d8ebbd5d721efa294e9602fb/dlls/ntdll/server.c#L584). So I'm going to assume that to emulate the behavior is not just a matter of the right posix calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a semaphore ([`sem_init`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init)), they work on shared memory. There's also named semaphores ([`sem_open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open)) if you want to initialize them from different processes. If you need to exchange messages with the workers, *e.g.* to pass the actual tasks to them, then one way to resolve this is to use [POSIX message queues](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview). They are named and work inter-process. Here's a short example. Note that only the first worker thread actually initializes the message queue, the others use the attributes of the existing one. Also, it (might) remain(s) persistent until explicitly removed using `mq_unlink`, which I skipped here for simplicity.

**Receiver with worker threads**:

```
// Link with -lrt -pthread

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *receiver_thread(void *param) {
    struct mq_attr mq_attrs = { 0, 10, 254, 0 };

    mqd_t mq = mq_open("/myqueue", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 00644, &mq_attrs);
    if(mq < 0) {
        perror("mq_open");
        return NULL;
    }
    char msg_buf[255];
    unsigned prio;

    while(1) {
        ssize_t msg_len = mq_receive(mq, msg_buf, sizeof(msg_buf), &prio);
        if(msg_len < 0) {
            perror("mq_receive");
            break;
        }
        msg_buf[msg_len] = 0;
        printf("[%lu] Received: %s\n", pthread_self(), msg_buf);
        sleep(2);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t workers[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, &receiver_thread, NULL);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

**Sender**:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    mqd_t mq = mq_open("/myqueue", O_WRONLY);
    if(mq < 0) {
        perror("mq_open");
    }
    char msg_buf[255];
    unsigned prio;

    for(int i=0; i<255; i++) {
        int msg_len = sprintf(msg_buf, "Message #%d", i);
        mq_send(mq, msg_buf, msg_len, 0);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I wonder why this solution is posted nowhere. This is EXACTLY what i am looking for. I can rebuild the named events with that, simply by sending the event name through the queue (to make it even faster, just enum the events and only send the number of the event through the queue). Thank you very much sir! (I can award the bounty in 20 hours)